# When I use ScrollintoView in Vue, using Behavior: Smooth doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

When I use ScrollintoView in Vue, using Behavior: Smooth doesn't work，this is my code:

```
let currentNode = document.getElementById(this.currentAppId);
      while (
        !(
          currentNode &&
          currentNode.previousElementSibling &&
          currentNode.previousElementSibling.classList.contains(
            "title-wrap"
          ) &&
          currentNode.classList.contains("content")
        )
      ) {
        currentNode = currentNode.parentElement;
      }
      currentNode.previousElementSibling.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth"
      })
```

Comment: Is `currentNode.previousElementSibling` defined? Are you using a browser that supports options for `scrollIntoView()`? Do you get any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: oh, Thank you for answering,This is a label that can be printed by the console. This scrolling is supported because it is normal for me to trigger this code with a button click, but it is not okay to trigger it with the input Enter event

Comment: How are you listening to the input enter event? Can you share a minimal, concrete and verifiable example?

Comment: ohhh, thanks ,this is my code about template

Comment: `<el-autocomplete
        class="inline-input"
        v-model="currentapp"
        :fetch-suggestions="querySearch"
        @keyup.native.enter="searchApp"
        @change="changeInput"
        placeholder="请输入关键字搜索应用"
        @select="handleSelect"
        :trigger-on-focus="autofocus"
      ></el-autocomplete>`